# How to tell the View to create a cookie?

Tags: php, mvc

I have a `LoginService` class with `loginUser($email, $password, $remember = false)` method in the application layer of my model layer.

Now, if `$remember` is `true` it needs to create a persistent user login cookie on the client's browser, but since that is the responsibility of the View, what is a good way of reaching the view through the controller to let it know it should create the cookie for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A View should not touch cookies. The place of the stored data (cookie, database, user table) is an implementation detail that a view should not know about, basically a [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) object.

Also `registerUser($email, $remember = false)` is not a good method signature. What if you have to pass more data for one of the cases later? This is hard to extend. Write different methods for different actions instead, `register_permanent( $email )` and `register_temporary( $email )` in this case.

The registration model should not know about cookies either, because cookies are a details of a web request, and the output layer (web, console, whatever) is another implementation detail that should not affect other business rules. 
The registration knows only what checks to apply for a registration. The CRUD object should be passed as an abstract dependency (an interface), so you can mock it easily in your unit tests.

An overly simplified solution could look like this:

```
interface Login_Status
{
    public function log_in( $name, $data );

    public function log_out( $name );

    public function get_data( $name );
}

class Login_Cookie implements Login_Status
{
    public function log_in( $name, $data )
    {
        setcookie( $name, $data, time() + 3600 * 24 * 30 );
    }

    public function log_out( $name )
    {
        setcookie( $name, '', time() + 3600 * 24 * 30 );
    }

    public function get_data( $name )
    {
        if ( ! empty ( $_COOKIE[ $name ] ) )
            return $_COOKIE[ $name ];

        return '';
    }
}

class User_Registration
{
    /**
     * @type Login_Status
     */
    private $login_Status;

    public function __construct( Login_Status $login_Status )
    {
        $this->login_Status = $login_Status;
    }

    public function register_permanent( $email )
    {
        // do something with $email, maybe this:
        $hash = hash( 'whirlpool', $email . 'some_salt' );
        // then …
        $this->login_Status->log_in( 'login', $hash );
    }
}
```

These models are controlled by … well … the controller. The view is not involved at all.

You could say that HTTP headers are output and therefore views. This is usually correct. But in this case, the view would just be a thin wrapper around `setcookie()` with some overhead (a dependency on a model). For the sake of simplicity, I would not separate out `setcookie()`.

Comment: **1)** I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my question. It supposed to be *Login* instead of *Register*. **2)** I guess this is all the result of HTTP being stateless, which makes it hard to really utilize the MVC pattern and the separation of concerns that come with it. What about doing redirection in the View, is that okay or should that happen in the Controller?

Comment: The view can sent headers, but what the *content* of these headers is – `Location`, `Content-Type` or something else – must be determined by a model. `setcookie()` mixes both, but that’s not enough reason to build your own alternative for that function. Pure MVC is almost impossible for web applications, because the controller cannot replace the view on runtime. It is also not necessary. Use MVC as a regulative idea to separate your logic, not as a fixed schema that dominates your application structure.

Comment: So redirection should happen in the model layer then? :o I never thought of that, other then the Controller or View to be a candidate for this.

Comment: A `Location` status header should be followed by a response body and an `exit`. Clearly a view. The URL and the status (30x) should be provided by a model.